# JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Tenho uma data no seguinte formato: **1424102400000** , ou seja, um valor inteiro. (Não sei bem dizer o nome desse formato).

Preciso converte-lo para um valor apresentável ao usuário, até aí tudo bem. Estou usando o método **toUTCString()** e também posso usar o [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/). Logo o valor apresentado anteriormente é o mesmo que **Mon, 16 Feb 2015 16:00:00 GMT**.

A questão é que tal valor apresentado ao usuário poderá ser alterado e então preciso converte-lo novamente para um valor inteiro semelhante ao padrão que apresentei inicialmente (claro que o valor será diferente caso o usuário tenha feito alguma alteração).

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Vejam [esse Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jedarc/f42h0u1q/), os valores não batem!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tp1dgjgv/

Comment: mude para valueOf() assim como falei, a diferença é que um é 1000 vezes maior, se voce usar o unix() e multiplicar por *1000 é praticamente a mesma coisa

Comment: esse formato parece ser timestamp, o problema acontece por causa dos milissegundos, set o valor de segundos e milissegundos para 0 na entrada e na saída;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se eu entendi certo você quer transformar do formato `UNIX TimeStamp` para um formato de exibição e depois poder converter de novo para o que era.

**Solução - MomentJS**

Use o método `moment()`

```
 var data = moment('seu valor em unix time stamp'); //retorna data
```

para retornar ao seu valor em Unix Time Stamp use:

```
 var timeStamp = moment(data).ValueOf(); //retorna Timestamp * 1000
```

O ValueOf() é igual a Unix() * 1000, pois mostra em milissegundos

Documentação momentJS: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-offset/

**Unix Time Stamp**

O formato Unix Time Stamp é a quantidade de segundos de diferença da data em relação a data Jan 01 1970. (UTC)

Correção do seu fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tp1dgjgv/

Comment: Você poderia fazer um fiddle de exemplo pra ficar mais claro com o valor que coloquei? **1424102400000** Transforma-lo em uma data, visualiza-la, converter para Unix, visualiza-lo e por último transforma-lo em data novamente para comparar as datas obtidas, por favor... O meu não está batendo.

Comment: infelizmente não consigo criar um JSfiddle para você agora, mas confira a documentação do  moment, teste seu código usando console.log() durante a execução e veja quais os outputs de cada comando

Answer (score 1):

Tente uma função

```
function IntToDate(i){
    var d = new Date(i);
    return moment(d.toUTCString());
}

IntToDate(1424102400000).format('DDMMYYYY');
```

Olhei rapidamente a  doc do `momentjs`, seja se é possivel alterar para passar o int direto sem necessidade do intermediário `date`